# not able to get sever.xml port settings in jira

Tags: jira

when i start jira in windows it starts successfully on default port 8080,
the situation is that i want another app to be started on same port,and when i search through /conf/server.xml i didnot find the connector port settings in that but when i go through GUI tool provided by jira i am able to get the port settings,

so my question is that how jira is implementing this, is there any other setting which jira is taking into consideration or something else.??

any suggetion...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jira does honor the conf/server.xml file. If you need to change the port number it should be set in the default connector (you can add this if it doesn't exist):

```
<Connector port="8082"
  maxThreads="150"
  minSpareThreads="25"
  maxSpareThreads="75"
  connectionTimeout="20000"

  enableLookups="false"
  maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
  protocol="HTTP/1.1"
  useBodyEncodingForURI="true"
  redirectPort="8443"
  acceptCount="100"
  disableUploadTimeout="true"/>
```

There is more information on the Atlassian Confluence site for Jira: https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Changing+JIRA's+TCP+Ports.

Also, you may want to consider http://www.serverfault.com for future questions, stackoverflow's brother for system administration Q&A.

Comment: thanks for your reply i did as you suggested and it is also working fine :)